# delete dumpstate/logcat from device

Tags: android, adb, android-logcat, android-os-handler

I Want to delete logs generated by the device from android phone using app or any code.

I tried using adb logcat -c this operation is not working until I kill ADB server(adb kill-server) and do adb logcat -c. I don't want to kill server as automation(Using appium) is running and killing adb server will also stop automation.

I tried searching in the internet and found a code *#9900# which is not working on the motorola phone(Moto E and Moto G).

So I'm thinking of to build an android app(new to android app development) to clear the logs. can any one suggest me is it possible to do this or any other possible ways with and without rooting phone

Comment: i dont get this point- `kill adb to clear logcat`. could ypu please elaborate ?

Comment: if i use this command adb logcat -c it doesn't do anything but after i kill adb -server and adb logcat -c then it clears logs

Comment: try `adb shell logcat -c`

Comment: i tried. its not working

Comment: I think there are two `adb` binaries in your pc. Appium is taking one and the shell your trying is taking from different location. Can you check that?